# Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments

Tags: swift

These two lines of code are giving me the

> Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments

error:

```
var w = Int(self.bounds.size.width / Float(worldSize.width))
var h = Int(self.bounds.size.height / Float(worldSize.height))
```

Comment: What is an `init`? What is a Cloud? Could you be more specific?

Comment: What type is worldSize.width?

Comment: Try creating the Float you use in your code on a separate line, then we can tell which operation is causing the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message is misleading. This should work:

```
var w = Int(self.bounds.size.width / CGFloat(worldSize.width))
var h = Int(self.bounds.size.height / CGFloat(worldSize.height))
```

The `width` and `height` elements of `CGSize` are declared as `CGFloat`.
On the 64-bit platform, `CGFloat` is the same as `Double` and has 64-bit,
whereas `Float` has only 32-bit.

So the problem is the division operator,
which requires two operands of the same type. In contrast to (Objective-)C, Swift never implicitly converts values to a 
different type.

If `worldSize` is also a `CGSize` then you do not need a cast at all:

```
var w = Int(self.bounds.size.width / worldSize.width)
var h = Int(self.bounds.size.height / worldSize.height)
```